# Android gallery problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gallery

i have a gallery, and over i have a text view if i click in an image it shows a text but i wanna when i scroll the gallery the text view shows a text too, for example if i scroll and the gallery image is a tree, the text view must show tree, i already have the event:

```
Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I'm looking for another without having to click the text show me

Comment: Do u have some screenshot or simple mock to explain more detail?

Comment: Thanks for anwer :) i could do that i wanted